# XLOOKUP unexpected behavior with spill range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup, spill-range

I have a table that looks something like this

| ID | Values 1 | Values 2 | Values 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 2 | 234 | 567 | 890 |
| 3 | 345 | 678 | 901 |
| 4 | 678 | 901 | 234 |

I'm using ID value to locate the row of interest (e.g. row ID=3) via either:

```
=CHOOSEROWS($A$1:$D$5,3)
```

or

```
=FILTER($A$1:$D$5,$A$1:$A$5=3)
```

I get a spill, say in row 6, that looks like this:

3 345 678 901

I'm trying to select a value from this row that is either matching or is next larger compared to a random number. Say, for a random number of 500 I would like to select the value 678. I'm trying:

```
=XLOOKUP(500,$A$6:$D$6,$A$6:$D$6,,1,)
```

but I'm always getting a result that is several columns off from what I'm trying to obtain (my actual table is quite bigger than this example). In this example I would get a number for Value 5, Value 6 and so on. What's even worse, this offset is always different based on which row I originally selected. Anyone has an idea how to make this work?

Comment: I do get `678` `=LET(f,FILTER($B$1:$D$5,$A$1:$A$5=3),XLOOKUP(500,f,f,,1))`

Comment: `=CHOOSEROWS($A$1:$D$5,3)` returns relative 3rd row while `=FILTER($A$1:$D$5,$A$1:$A$5=3)` returns row where *ID=3* which is 4th relative row. Your `XLOOKUP` returns correct result. In first case it is `567` in second `678`

Comment: Apologies, the `=CHOOSEROWS($A$1:$D$5,3)` should say `=CHOOSEROWS($A$1:$D$5,MATCH(3,$A$1:$A$5))`. Nevertheless, I still have the same XLOOKUP error, perhaps because my ranges are actually spill ranges. Instead of `$A$6:$D$6` I actually have `$A$6#`. I'm still getting the same error. I will try to upload a sheet with the actual data.

Comment: Also, the range I pull this information from via CHOOSEROWS and FILTER is an actual named table, not regular cells.

Comment: You can't use spill ranges in actual tables